# Getting 401 / 403 errors trying to upload a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, swfupload

I'm using [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/) jquery plugin that uses SWFUpload.

Currently it's not working at all. I've put breakpoints in at:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And when I choose my file it doesn't appear to even hit the server. If I keep trying to upload a file without refreshing the page I get 401/403 errors alternating. I've tried loads of different files, in places like my desktop, my documents folder etc.

How can I stop this issue and get SWFUpload working?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is using AJax, it needs to hit an ActionMethod in your controller

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(){


//find the code somwhere


}
```

Comment: I've already got that method. My point is the authorisation error appears to happen without hitting the server at all.